# Oracle APEX (Foreign Key) Column Not Showing in Interactive Report

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

These are the columns in my table for the interactive report:
[image]

The selected column, `WORD_ID`, is the column that is not showing in my interactive report; it is also a foreign key to the table. (I tried to make it a link because that is what I ultimately want to do, but the column wasn't showing up even when it was just plain text.)

In the actual report:
[image]

There doesn't appear to be a `WORD_ID` column at all.

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the "Select Columns" screen is what users see: those are the column *labels*. In the first screenshot - the one from the builder, you see the   actual column *names* or *aliases* from the query/table. The report in the builder has 5 columns to show and 2 hidden ones. The "Select Columns" screen also has 5 columns (1 hidden, 4 displayed), so all looks fine. My guess is that the column "WORD_ID" has label "Word". Show all columns in the report and verify the labels.